# How can I execute consecutive commands from a command prompt?

Tags: windows, vbscript

How can I execute two consecutive commands on the command line with the help of  `wshshell.exec` or `wshshell.run` in vbscript? For example I need to execute `cd C:\a` and then `winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a`.

Comment: Please put your question in the question, not the title.

Comment: sure. i will keep that in mind from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like `cd C:\a & winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a` where the `&` separates commands so the that second one runs once the first has finished successfully. For example, you could run it like this:

```
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c cd C:\a & winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a")
```

Without the `cmd /c` in the beginning, you can't do things like `cd` because cmd.exe is responsible for processing the `cd` and `&`.

Comment: i tried
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/vbscript">

Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("cd C:\a & winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo oExec.Status
</script>
</body>
</html>
but nothing is happening

Comment: Where are you using that HTML? In a HTA or a normal web page? Just wondering cause normally WshShell cannot be created in a web page as it is considered unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you could use WshShell.Exec "c:\a\winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a"